# Replace 0 value in covariance matrix (pmvnorm)

Tags: r

so I'm using pmvnorm and a cycle for, as the elements in the covariance matrix can change according to the value of some parameters:

```
y<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

....

```
library(mvtnorm)
mu=c(18,12.72,(18*(c-d)+12.72*f))
covariance=matrix(c(5.7,0,5.7*(c-d),0,30.38,30.38*f^2,5.7*(c-d),30.38*f,(5.7*(c-d)^2+30.38*f^2)),3)
H=c(15,-Inf,-Inf)
L=c(Inf,15,g)
for(i in 1:10)
y[i]=pmvnorm(mean=mu,sigma=covariance,lower=H,upper=L)
```

where c,d,f etc were already defined.
It works but,in some cases I have the third r.v that has 0 variance and it appears an error. Is it possible to replace in the covariance matrix 0 value with very small value (as 1e-06?)

Thank you

Comment: What are `c`, `d`, `f`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to replace 0s with a very small value (as 1e-06)

```
covariance = matrix(c(0,2,3,0), ncol = 2)
covariance[covariance == 0] <- 1e-06
covariance
```

If this doesnt help Pascal is right, some details about your parameter could be helpful to look in to the positive definiteness problem of your covariance matrices.